# How to capture second match from the given text using regex

Tags: regex, irule

I tried to capture the second match from given text i.e,

```
hash=e1467eb30743fb0a180ed141a26c58f7&token=a62ef9cf-2b4e-4a99-9335-267b6224b991:IO:OPCA:117804471:OPI:false:en:opsdr:117804471&providerId=paytm
```

In the above text, I want to capture the second number with the length of 9 (117804471).

I tried following, but it didn't work; so please help me resolving in this.

https://regex101.com/r/vBJceR/1

Comment: simply use `\d{9}` to capture the digit of length 9.

Comment: `^(?:.*?\K\b[0-9]{9}\b)`? See https://regex101.com/r/YeDFCe/2

Comment: Sorry, forgot it should be the second occurrence, you need to add `{2}` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```r
^(?:.*?\K\b[0-9]{9}\b){2}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/YeDFCe/3).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars (as few as possible) followed with
  - `\K` - match reset operator discarding text matched so far
  - `\b[0-9]{9}\b` - a 9-digit number as a whole word
- `){2}`  - two occurrences of the pattern sequence defined above.